# Get a collection of all IOptions objects with autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, ioptions

I'd like to be able to get a collection of all `IOptions<T>` registered in autofac so that I can save them to a custom JSON file. Something like:

```
class OptionsManager(IEnumerable IOptions)
```

I don't know if this is even possible because there is not AFAIK a non-generic `IOptions` interface, and currently I don't actually register the options per se, I build a service collection that adds them, and that gets populates my container via an extension:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection().AddOptions();
builder.Populate(serviceCollection);
```

Which doesn't expose any way for me to reigster the these options under a single interface anyways.

I could register all my classes under my own generic interface, `IOptions` or a common base class or something. But this doesn't prevent me from using a class outside of this interface as an `IOptions<T>` and further, I don't think the classes I register would be the same as the ones provided by the `IOptions<T>` registration, so it wouldn't even work.

I could just abandon `IOptions<T>` all together, but that means I have to expose my own `Options` interface for others to implement, which I can do, but I would rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following sample register to `IOptions<object>` :
Console app, Package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` ``
Appsettings.json

```
{
  "Option1": {
    "Name": "Tom"
  },
  "Option2": {
    "Age": 14
  }
}
```

option type

```
    public class Option1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Option2 
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
builder.Register(c => Options.Create(config.GetSection("Option1").Get<Option1>())).As<IOptions<object>>();
builder.Register(c => Options.Create(config.GetSection("Option2").Get<Option2>())).As<IOptions<object>>();

var container = builder.Build();

var optionsList = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IOptions<object>>>();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Test result
[image]